# Angular 4 pattern validation from component

Tags: html, regex, angular, typescript

I am not able to bind variable from component as a pattern with Angular 4.
This code works:

```
<textarea #sss="ngModel"
    class="form-control"
    id="sss"
    maxlength="350"
    pattern="[a-zA-Z '-,;.]*"
    [(ngModel)]="formModel.sss" name="sss"></textarea>
```

But when I try to add something like:

```
export class SssComponent {
    public sssPattern: string = "[a-zA-Z '-,;.]*";
```

and add it like that:

```
<textarea #sss="ngModel"
    class="form-control"
    id="sss"
    maxlength="350"
    pattern="sssPattern"
    [(ngModel)]="formModel.sss" name="sss"></textarea>
```

it don't. Also tried variations like:

```
[pattern]="sssPattern"
[pattern]={{sssPattern}}
pattern={{sssPattern}}
```

with no success. Angular 4

Comment: Shouldn't it be a `RegExp`? `public sssPattern: RegExp = /^[a-zA-Z ',;.-]*$/;` (or something like that)?

Comment: not working even with that

Comment: Well, just mind that you need to anchor the pattern manually if you are not using `Validators` and that `-` in between chars in a character class creates a range (so, it must be at the end or start of the character class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You have to use `attr.pattern`, because pattern is an attribute with no reflection from a property:</strike>

```
<textarea [attr.pattern]="sssPattern"></textarea>
```

> Interpolation and property binding can set only properties, not
>   attributes.
>
> You need attribute bindings to create and bind to such attributes.
>
> Attribute binding syntax resembles property binding. Instead of an
>   element property between brackets, start with the prefix `attr`,
>   followed by a dot (.) and the name of the attribute. You then set the
>   attribute value, using an expression that resolves to a string.

[read more](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding)

You cannot use `pattern` on a `textarea`. Angular does have its own [`PatternValidator`](https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator), which means all that nonsense I said about `attr` does not hold up for this specific case, but I believe this does not work on a textarea, because [`textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) itself does not contain the `pattern` attribute in standard `HTML5`, as opposed to the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) element.

In order to use a pattern on a `textarea`, you should create a `CustomValidator`

Comment: @TeodorKolev are you using single quotes here? `'[a-zA-Z '-,;.]*'`, because that would be a syntax error.. You have to escape the single quote inside the regex. Do you have any error coming up?

Comment: I use doule quotes actually

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52091334/password-validation-is-not-working-in-angular-5 @PierreDuc

Answer (score 2):

If you use Angular Forms, below code can be used for field and pattern validation

```
let emailFormat = "[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+\\.[a-z]{2,3}";
let nameFormat = "[a-zA-Z\s]+$";

this.name = new FormControl("", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(nameFormat)]));
this.email = new FormControl("", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(emailFormat)]));
```